# Testing useDispach with jest

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to test `useDispach` using jest.

This is my component `ItemInput.js`:

```
const ItemInput = ({ value, title, action, type, placeholder }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    return (
        <div>
            <span data-cy="title">{title}</span>

            <Input
                type={type}
                value={value}
                onChange={e =>
                    dispatch({
                        type: action,
                        payload: { value: e.target.value }
                    })
                }
                placeholder={placeholder}
                data-cy={`item-input-${title}`}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

and here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ItemInput from '../ItemInput';

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
const store = mockStore({});
const setup = () => {
    const props = {
        action: 'SET_NAME',
        value: 'test',
        title: 'title',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: ''
    };

    const component = mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ItemInput {...props} />
        </Provider>
    );

    const input = component.find(`[data-cy="item-input-${props.title}"]`).first();

    return {
        component,
        input,
        props
    };
};

describe('ItemInput', () => {
    it('should render correctly', () => {
        const { component } = setup();
        expect(component.find('ItemInput').exists()).toEqual(true);
    });

    it('should call dispach when typing', () => {
        const { input, props } = setup();
        store.dispatch = jest.fn();
        input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Jack' } });

        expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            type: props.action,
            payload: { value: 'Jack' }
        });
    });
});
```

expected behaviour is that `dispatch` is called with `{type: props.action,payload: { value: 'Jack'}}`.

but got an error :

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: {"payload": {"value": "Jack"}, "type": "SET_NAME"}

Number of calls: 0

  60 |         input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Jack' } });
  61 | 
> 62 |         expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
     |                                ^
  63 |             type: props.action,
  64 |             payload: { value: 'Jack' }
  65 |         });
```

I think there is some problem with`input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Jack' } });` that it does not trigger the dispatch function.

Any idea how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Answering your question**, the problem is that you are mocking the store `dispatch` method after mounting your component.

This causes that the component is mounted with the original value of the `store` and your mock is not taken into account.

To solve this you only need to change the order of your test so that the `dispatch` mock takes place before the usage of the store:

```
it('should call dispatch when typing', () => {
    store.dispatch = jest.fn();
    const { input, props } = setup();
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Jack' } });

    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        type: props.action,
        payload: { value: 'Jack' }
    });
});
```

**As an alternative solution**, as you are already using `redux-mock-store` library, you can get all the actions triggered by calling `store.getActions`. So, a cleaner way to test that the action has been triggered is:

```
it('should call dispatch when typing', function() {
    const { input, props } = setup();
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Jack' } });

    const actions = store.getActions();
    expect(actions).toEqual([{
        type: props.action,
        payload: { value: 'Jack' }
    }]);
});
```

Comment: Hi, @mgarcia, thanks for the answer, I have implemented your solution but I still have the same error.

Comment: Maybe you have something different? I put together this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-dawn-cwf3u?file=/src/ItemInput.test.js) so that you can compare.

Comment: Thanks for the code sandbox, I have literally copied and pasted the code and got the same error. Such a weird thing :/.  I may have some missing configuration? Do you know if is there any other approach to test useDispatch?

Comment: Hi @GN, I have included an alternative solution that should work. Hope it helps!